# How can I get unicode characters from a URL parameter?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

I need to use a GET request to send JSON to my server via a JavaScript client, so I started echoing responses back to make sure nothing is lost in translation. There doesn't seem to be a problem with normal text, but as soon as I include a Unicode character of any sort (e.g. "ç") the character is encoded somehow (e.g. "\u00e7") and the return value is different from request value. My primary concern is that, **A)** In my Python code saves what the client intended on sending to the database correctly, and **B)** I echo the same values back to the client that were sent (when testing).

Perhaps this means I can't use base64, or have to do something different along the way. I'm ok with that. My implementation is just an attempt at a means to an end.

### Current steps (any step can be changed, if needed):

Raw JSON string which I want to send to the server:

```
'{"weird-chars": "°ç"}'
```

JavaScript [Base64 encoded](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) version of the string passed to server via GET param (on a side note, will the equals sign at the end of the encoded string cause any issues?):

```
http://www.myserver.com/?json=eyJ3ZWlyZC1jaGFycyI6ICLCsMOnIn0=
```

Python `str` result from `b64decode` of param:

```
'{"weird-chars": "\xc2\xb0\xc3\xa7"}'
```

Python `dict` from `json.loads` of decoded param:

```
{'weird-chars': u'\xb0\xe7'}
```

Python `str` from `json.dumps` of that `dict` (and subsequent output to the browser):

```
'{"weird-chars": "\u00b0\u00e7"}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks fine to me.

```
>>> hex(ord(u'°'))
'0xb0'
>>> hex(ord(u'ç'))
'0xe7'
```

Perhaps you should decode the JSON before attempting to use it.

Comment: @Ignacio - I can't simply loop through each character in the string and convert it using `hex(ord(char))`. Is there a way I can guarantee that the characters are going to be stored in the DB correctly (during the Python `dict` step above), and also return them back to the browser correctly (ie, not encoded), all while not causing any issues or potential bugs? By correctly, I mean that if the user types `ççç` as their name, when they come back to the page, their name doesn't show up as `0xe70xe70xe7`.

Comment: @Ignacio - How is `loads` getting me the "decoded" value, if it's still `\xb0\xe7` hex encoded? I'm just trying to understand. Is `°` supposed to be stored as `xb0` in the database, etc and so you consider that to be "decoded"? Or, are you suggesting to "decode" it some other way before running `loads`? in my example above, I'm already using `loads`, in the second from last step. The browser is still receiving the string from the last step, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Ignacio - ok, that makes sense now. Why is the browser receiving the same thing as what `repr()` shows? Is there a step I'm missing at the end?

Comment: @Ignacio - ok, thanks. I previously thought you just meant decode on the server side in your answer.

Comment: How would you use the JSON on the client without decoding it?

Comment: @Ignacio - I will decode it from JSON to a JavaScript object, but I didn't want to have to also decode special characters. JSON doens't require ASCII only characters. If I replace `json.dumps(my_dict)` with `json.dumps(my_dict, ensure_ascii=False)`, it works without encoding Unicode characters. Would that be wrong to do?

Comment: Being able to handle the "special characters" is part of JSON. If whatever you're using to decode it can't handle them, then it's not a JSON library.

Comment: That's what I'll do then. I'm not trying to argue the correct way. I'm simply trying to understand the "why" of the "correct" way, so that I don't go the wrong direction. I want the API users to be able to be able to use standard practices and not have to take extra steps, but it sounds like you're saying any `JSON.decode()` method in JS will do the appropriate conversions.

Comment: I don't know that *any* `JSON.decode()` will work. But the ones built into the browsers as well as the one supplied in `json2.js` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Your procedure's fine, you just need 1 more step; that is, encoding from unicode to `utf-8` (or any other encoding that supports the 'weird characters'.)

Think of *decoding* as what you do to go from a regular string *to* unicode and *encoding* as what you do to get back *from* unicode. In other words:

You *de* - code a `str` to produce a `unicode` string

and *en* - code a `unicode` string to produce an `str`.

So:

```
params = {'weird-chars': u'\xb0\xe7'}

encodedchars = params['weird-chars'].encode('utf-8')
```

`encodedchars` will contain your characters, displayed in the selected encoding (in this case, `utf-8`).