# unicode().decode('utf-8', 'ignore') raising UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: unicode, python-2.x

Here is the code:

```
>>> z = u'\u2022'.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2022' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Why is UnicodeEncodeError raised when I am using .decode?

Why is any error raised when I am using 'ignore'?

Comment: Note this wouldn't happen in Python 3. In Python 3, running that code would give you this error instead: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. This is when of the advantages of Python 3: it enforces the distinction between string/unicode objects and bytes objects. You use `decode` to convert a string to a bytes objects, and you use `encode` to convert a bytes object to a string, and the distinction between `decode` and `encode` is much easier to grasp.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

When I first started messing around with python strings and unicode, It took me awhile to understand the jargon of *decode* and *encode* too, so here's my post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474430/how-can-i-get-unicode-characters-from-a-url-parameter/4474614#4474614) that may help:

---

Think of *decoding* as what you do to go from a regular bytestring *to* unicode and *encoding* as what you do to get back *from* unicode. In other words:

You *de*-code a `str` to produce a `unicode` string (in Python 2)

and *en*-code a `unicode` string to produce a `str` (in Python 2)

So:

```
unicode_char = u'\xb0'

encodedchar = unicode_char.encode('utf-8')
```

`encodedchar` will contain your unicode character, displayed in the selected encoding (in this case, `utf-8`).

The same principle applies to Python 3. You *de*-code a `bytes` object to produce a `str` object. And you *en*-code a `str` object to produce a `bytes` object.

Comment: Python 3 has much clearer notion of encoded **byte-arrays** and abstract (Unicode) character **strings**.

Comment: It should be noted that this is surely the correct answer to what must’ve been F.C.’s underlying problem, but people coming here because they encounter this seemingly paradoxical behavior when they didn’t notice that a small fraction of the strings they try to decode are already Unicode strings are probably better served by the other answers.

Comment: `u'KEEP ME ㉃‰䥈啌ੁ剆䕅 KEEP ME ALSO'.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii','ignore')  # worked for me`

Comment: @DaveKierans That will throw away all non-ascii characters in the string (those Chinese ones, for example). Make sure that's what you want!

Answer (score 21):

From http://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeEncodeError

> Paradoxically, a UnicodeEncodeError may happen when
>      *decoding*. The cause of it seems to be the
>      coding-specific decode() functions that normally expect
>      a parameter of type str. It appears that on seeing a
>      unicode parameter, the decode() functions "down-convert"
>      it into str, then decode the result assuming it to be of
>      their own coding. It also appears that the
>      "down-conversion" is performed using the ASCII encoder.
>      Hence an encoding failure inside a decoder.

Comment: This seems like pure madness. If you call decode() on a unicode object, I would expect it to simply return the object as it was, since clearly it is already a unicode object...

Comment: @rkrzr In Python 3, you can't call `decode` on a str/unicode object, only on bytes objects.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to decode a `unicode`. The implicit encoding to make the decode work is what's failing.

Comment: so I wonder why is there a decode method in unicode objects and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: It's handy when using non-text codecs such as `unicode-escape`. It still encodes it to `str` though, before decoding.

Comment: handy? "Explicit is better than Implicit" and "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules"

Comment: @FacundoCasco In Python 3, there isn't a `decode` method in str/unicode objects, only in bytes objects.

Comment: sometime works if you put  `encoding('utf-8', 'ignore'))`