# Issues in Reading MemoryObject of file

Tags: python, python-3.x

- I have a function who reads `MemoryObject` of file. It is reading most of the files but for one file it is raising `UnicodeDecodeError`.

here is my code

```
def read(file):
    """

    :param file: File Memory Object (submitted from POST)
    :return: File Iterable object
    """

    file = StringIO(file.read().decode())
    return csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
```

- [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XlFoCdqz-RKh2JNUU6O8ZEOruRYtTn2M/view?usp=sharing) which raise no issue.
- [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YKlPiwB0xs-kfKSyX2w105IxvOAKYUgq/view?usp=sharing) which is rasing issue.

Complete error is as follows : `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

- In other question where user have asked questions of similar errors. they are using `open()` to streamline the file but I already have streamline MemoryObject so can't use `open()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Throwing "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117836/python-throwing-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xd0-in-position-0-error)

Comment: @Caramiriel here they are using `open()` to steamline the file whereas I already have `Memoryobject` which so can't use open().

Comment: Is the error thrown at the line including `.decode()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `file` is already opened in binary mode: [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) is a method of `bytes`, not `str`.

For your problem, the `encoding` and `errors` parameter of `bytes.decode` works the same as for `open`. You can apply the appropriate encoding, or ignore errors:

```
def read(file, encoding: str = 'utf-8', errors: str = 'strict'):
    """
    :param file: File Memory Object (submitted from POST)
    :return: File Iterable object
    """

    file = StringIO(file.read().decode(encoding=encoding, errors=errors))
    return csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
```

Note that you either *must* know the encoding, or suppress errors by ignoring them. You can try different encodings to find one that works, but in the end you must know what your data means.

Comment: -**FIrst** I am getting this error for ignore keyword `TypeError: 'ignore' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`.
**Secondly** : The nature of my data is same in both file I shared but one file (**working**) is created from `LIbre office` using `Text CSV format` and other one (not working) created from `MIcrosoft office (microsoft excel 97-2003 format)` even if this file is blank it will still not work.

Comment: @user5594493 I have fixed the keyword, as shown in the documentation. Note that you did not share any files, both links are invalid.

Comment: still no success ... I have updated the file links in my original question