# Failure to decode numerical html entities in Python 3.4

Tags: python, decode, html-entities, utf8-decode

I use Python 3.4 for Windows. I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string) in SO:

```
import html
print(html.unescape('&#pound;682'))
```

Yet it does not work, neither it works with **numeric encoded value: £**

```
import html
print(html.unescape('&#163;682'))
```

The error is:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

### Update

Thanks to Kevin I've found this useful:

```
print(html.unescape('&#163;682m'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')))
```

yet another error:

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
>   What else can I try to decode it?

Comment: It works for me, using Python 3.5, on Arch Linux.

Comment: @KevinGuan, am I missing any library?

Comment: Well, I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947092/codec-cant-encode-character-character-maps-to-undefined). Maybe the problem is about the encode.

Comment: @KevinGuan, `print (sys.stdout.encoding)` returns **cp866**. Can/Should I change it?

Comment: Actually I don't know, just say that I found a question has the same problem.

Comment: On Windows, your best bet is to write it into a file (use utf-8 for encoding). The windows commandline and encodings are not good friends.