# Python 3.4, Decoding error for byte '\x93'

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, python-3.4

I am simply reading a file in binary mode into a buffer, performing some replacements on that buffer and after that inserting that buffered data into MySQL database. Every byte got inserted regardless of any encoding standard. I used `python 2.7`, it worked well.

**CODE :**

```
with open(binfile,'rb') as fd_bin:
   bin_data = fd_bin.read()
   bin_data = bin_data.replace('"','\\"')
   db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table BIN_DATA values {}".format(bin_data))
```

When I used `python 3.4` version, it needed to be decoded so I used :

```
   bin_data = fd_bin.read()
   bin_data = bin_data.decode('utf-8') # error at this line
```

The mentioned second line produced error:

```
bindata = bindata.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 1:invalid
start byte
```

I used `latin-1` and `iso-8859-1` decoding scheme but they insert some extra byte at some places. when I fetch data from database, data is not same in this case but it was for python 2.7 version.

How can I insert that data or decode that data regardless of encoding scheme ? I can't skip or ignore the bytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unicode().decode('utf-8', 'ignore') raising UnicodeEncodeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096776/unicode-decodeutf-8-ignore-raising-unicodeencodeerror)

Comment: Honestly, this question was around on StackOverflow so many, many, many times.