# Convert exception to unicode in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

In legacy code the original exception gets caught in the variable `exc`:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 32] Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)>
```

I want to use `unicode(exc)` but this fails:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 31:
                     ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I create a unicode string from the exception `exc`?

Environment: Python 2.7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096776/unicode-decodeutf-8-ignore-raising-unicodeencodeerror

Comment: You should not be writing new code in Python 2 in 2018.

Comment: @tripleee you know more than I do. You know when the above code was written? I don't.

Comment: Obviously, maintaining Python 2 code is going to be a thing for a long time still. Your question reads like you are trying to actually develop Python 2 code, though.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for this hint. I updated the question. Is it correct now?

Comment: Showing the actual code which produces the exception would still be a welcome addition. See also the [help] guidance for creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

This

```
unicode(exc)
```

is failing because `exc` is of type `URLError`, and if you try to do string operations on it (like converting to Unicode) Python does an implicit string conversion, and the encoding it assumes is `'ascii'`. To do what you want you have to get the string out of the exception yourself, and supply the encoding you want, like this:

```
unicode(exc.reason, encoding='Latin-1')
```

For a solution that will work for other types of exception, decode the members of the tuple `exc.args` individually:

```
", ".join(unicode(a, encoding='Latin-1') for a in exc.args)
```

There is no generic way to tell which member of `args` is the one you really want to see, but it will usually be the first one.

Comment: If I try this with a different exception I get an AttributeError because the exception does not have the attribute "reason".

Comment: Edited to take account of the broadened question.